# Block read until data available in memfd_create

Tags: c, linux, file, ld-preload

I'm trying to create a file in memory, which behaves just like a character device. I've used `memfd_create(path, 0)`, but I'm starting to think this is not what I need.
In essence what I want to do is create a hook via LD_PRELOAD on open, look for `open("/dev/input/event0")` and change the returned fd to my memfd. Then I want to create a sort of queue for the hooked app to read from just like it would if it were a read device file.

However read() seems to not block when used on my memfd even if there are 0 bytes to be read. Could you point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

As requested I'm providing the code, however I'm not quite sure if this will be of any help since it is literally two lines...

```
struct input_event ev;
int kbd = memfd_create("/dev/input/event0", 0);
read(kbd, &ev, sizeof(ev)); //<-- How can I make this block by default?
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. Use a pipe instead of a memfd.
Then write from one end and read in the hooked app.

```
int kbd[2];
struct input_event ev;
pipe(kbd);
read(kbd[0], &ev, sizeof(ev));
```